# UITableView within a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I need to load a `UITableViewCell` xib into the root controller of a split view. The `UITableViewCell` contains a `UITableView` as a subview (designed in Interface Builder). This `UITableView` will be used to load other cells. Is the loading of the `UITableView` within the `UITableViewCell` possible to achieve??

In short - a cell with a tableview as a subview that loads data from DB.

I have tried this but with little success. The problem is that the delegate method...

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

..placed within the `UITableViewCell` implementation file, never gets triggered.

Please help.

Comment: **Why** in the many hot Hells do you want to do that?

Comment: Well, you could use it to put a few grouped table cells in a non-grouped table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design may be ill advised, however...

If you have code for your UITableViewCell class, then that object needs to be the data source and delegate for your embedded UITableView. Something, certainly, has to be the tableView's data source and delegate, of course.

Another best practice, in this case, would certainly to be to make sure that the `tableView` argument in the various data source and delegate methods is the tableView object you think it is before you do anything.

How many custom table cells with embedded table views are you planning? Why not use a single table view with Grouped style? Eacn section of the table can then contain the content that you are now putting into your UITableViewCell/UITableView element. Would certainly be simpler, and might achieve the same result.

Comment: I re-linked the UITableView with the UITableViewCell class (datasource and delegate) at now it is working.